# Getting URL Kwargs into Django ListView Object Attributes

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I've got a class-based-view and I'm trying to implement breadcrumbs into it.

I'm using django-bootstrap-breadcrumbs & django-view-breadcrumbs, but because of our unique URL structure we have an ID in the URL of almost all of the urls.

I've setup the breadcrumbs appropriately, but need to get the `person_id` kwarg into the 'crumbs' attribute on the ListView

URLs look like this:

```
    path(
        "<person_id>/trees/",
        views.TreeListView.as_view(),
        name="tree_list",
    ),
    path(
        "<person_id>/trees/<pk>/",
        views.TreeDetailView.as_view(),
        name="tree_view",
    ),
    path(
        "<person_id>/trees/<tree_id>/planes/",
        views.PlaneListView.as_view(),
        name="plane_list",
    ),
    path(
        "<person_id>/trees/<tree_id>/cord/<pk>/",
        views.CordDetailView.as_view(),
        name="cord_view",
    ),
```

I've setup my view according to the documentation:

```
class TreeListView(
        LoginRequiredMixin,
        UserPassesTestMixin,
        ListBreadcrumbMixin,
        ListView
    ):
    # pylint: disable=too-many-ancestors
    login_url = "/login/"
    model = Tree
    template_name = "tree_list"
    crumbs = [('My Test Breadcrumb', reverse('tree_list', args=[self.kwargs["person_id"]]))]
```

As you can see in the last line - the crumbs is what is supposed to create the breadcrumbs that display on the page.

The issue is that I get an error (which seem pretty obvious) that there is no 'self' item with that object.

My question is - how do I get that `person_id` from the URL so I can pass it as the argument to the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `crumbs` as property:

```
class TreeListView(
        LoginRequiredMixin,
        UserPassesTestMixin,
        ListBreadcrumbMixin,
        ListView
    ):
    # pylint: disable=too-many-ancestors
    login_url = "/login/"
    model = Tree
    template_name = "tree_list"

    @property
    def crumbs(self):
        return [('My Test Breadcrumb', reverse('tree_list', args=[self.kwargs["person_id"]]))]
```

Comment: Just so I know for my own knowledge, does the `@property` decorator make the function name get treated like an object attribute but give us access to the 'self', object?

Comment: @Hanny Yes, you can now use `crumbs` as normal attribute. E.g. `TreeListView.crumbs` is correct syntax now.

Comment: I see that! I had never used the `@property` decorator before, so this was a treat. Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: @Hanny there are many interesting things you can do with property. You can get some initial info here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property